# Graph Theory - Degree of vertices proof

Tags: graph-theory

Here's a problem I've been assigned in my graph theory class:

The degree of every vertex of a graph $G$ of order $2n+1\ge5$ is either $n+1$ or $n+2.$ Prove that $G$ contains at least $n+1$ vertices of degree $n+2$ or $n+2$ vertices of degree $n+1.$

I could use some help getting started with this one. My first thought is to utilise the first theorem of Graph Theory, but doing so hasn't led to anything useful. Thanks.

Comment: Proof by contradiction: suppose the said graph has less then $n+1$ vertices of degree $n+2$ AND less than $n+2$ vertices of degree $n+1$, then....

Comment: In which case there are at most (n+1)-1=n vertices of order n+2, and (n+2)-1 = n+1 vertices of order n+1. So the sum of all degrees is n(n+2)+(n+1)^2 = 2n^2+4n+1. How do I proceed without knowing the size of the graph?

Comment: What is the first theorem of graph theory? Is that the one that says the sum of the degrees of all the vertices is an even number, equl to twice the number of edges?

Comment: Yes it is. Sum of all degv = 2m, where m is the size of G.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1$ be the number of vertices with degree $n+1$, $x_2$ be the number of vertices with degree $n+2$.

For the sake of contradiction, assume that $x_1 < n+2$ **AND** $x_2 < n+1$.

Thus $x_1 \leq n+1$, $x_2 \leq n$. We know that $x_1 + x_2 = 2n+1$. This equality only holds when $x_1 = n+1$ **AND** $x_2 = n$.

Thus the sum of degree across all nodes is

$$
(n+1)(n+1) + (n)(n+2) = 2n^2 + 4n + 1
$$

Which is clearly odd. However, the sum of all degrees in a graph must be even. Contradiction.

Thus $x_1 \geq n+2$ **OR** $x_2 \geq n+1$

Comment: But of course, the sum of degrees is odd. Much better. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @J.Hunt Your question has got two answers now. Are you aware that you can **accept** an answer? All you have to do is click on the check mark next to whichever answer choose.

Answer (score 0):

Proof (By Contradiction): Suppose the graph has less than n+1 vertices of degree n+2 and less than n+2 vertices of degree n+1 (i.e., there are at most (n+1)-1=n vertices of degree n+2, and at most (n+2)-1=n+1 vertices of degree n+1). Then the sum of all degrees is at most n(n+2)+(n+1)(n+1)=n^2+2n+n^2+2n+1=2n^2+4n+1. By the first theorem of graph theory, this is 2m, where m is the size of G. The size of G is unknown, but it can be no greater than if G is a complete graph. The complete graph has size z(z-1)/2, where z is the order; so if G is complete, then it has size {(2n+1)[(2n+1)-1]}/2 = (4n^2+2n)/2. So the sum of all degrees is 2n^2+4n+1 = 2m = 4n^2+2n. But 2n^2+4n+1 > 4n^2+2 for all n≥2; this is a contradiction. Any other such graph that is not complete will have a size less than that of this complete one. Thus they will lead to contradictions as well. Therefore G contains at least n+1 vertices of degree n+2, or at least n+2 vertices of degree n+1. QED.

Is this reasonable?